# Why inputStream randomly comes empty while capturing the output from ProcessBuilder?

Tags: java, linux, grep, processbuilder

I found similar questions here at SO, but no solution worked for me.

My code is

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
int ret = 0;
while (rs.next()) {
    int rsID = rs.getInt("ID");
    String rsGID = rs.getString("GID");
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "");
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "ID / GID: {0}", rsID + " / " + rsGID);
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(new String[] { "bash", "-c", "grep " + rsGID + " /media/newdrive/*"});
    Process proc = builder.redirectErrorStream(true).start();
    //while (proc.isAlive());
    String smatch = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(new String(proc.getInputStream().readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).replaceAll("\\R", "");
    ret = proc.waitFor();
    String sURL = StringUtils.substringBefore(StringUtils.substringAfter(smatch, "<loc>"), "</loc>");
    String sField = StringUtils.substringAfterLast(StringUtils.substringBefore(smatch, "."), "/").replaceAll("[0-9_]", "");
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "URL: {0}", rsID + " / " + sURL);
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Field: {0}", rsID + " / " + sField);
    proc.destroy();
}
rs.close();
```

What happens is that I get randomly an empty outcome for the first pair of results:

[image: Two sets of outcomes]

My **workaround** is to call isAlive method within a while loop. So, in my code as I uncomment it and comment waitFor line, I always get the first pair of results.

Am I misusing waitFor? Looks like lots of developers face the same problem.

Guidance will be appreciated.

BTW, I choose to use native grep because of performance matters. We have 100+ XML files, with ~200,000 lines each and 1000+ GID to match periodically.

**UPDATE**

I change the code to

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outError = new ByteArrayOutputStream();                
Process proc = builder.redirectErrorStream(false).start();
proc.getErrorStream().transferTo(outError);
```

but no luck, I still receive empty results once in a while.

So, finally after many tests, even `while (proc.isAlive());` fails.

For now I put a block of code before the ResultSet loop, that starts and end a Process with fake data. As those empty random results appeared only on first Process execution, now I have always reliable data being created inside the ResultSet loop. Extensively tested.

Comment: I didn't test it, so no full answer, but could it be that `proc.getInputStream().readAllBytes()` just reads all bytes that are available *at the time of calling* and sometimes the bytes are just coming in after that? I would get the input stream, but consume it fully after the process has finished.

Comment: But just as I read this: are you sure you need a java wrapper around grep here? Can you maybe extract the IDs to scan into a file and then use `xargs` to execute `grep`, and then cut the required results with `cut`? Can't tell exactly, because you only described the problem in the approach you took, not the overall goal

Comment: It's important to consume both inputstreams corectly, maybe my articel could help you: https://thilosdevblog.wordpress.com/2022/09/18/how-to-properly-handle-the-output-of-the-processbuilder/

Comment: No need to use grep.  You have Java.  Use `boolean match = Files.list(Path.of("/media/newdrive")).anyMatch(file -> Files.lines(file).anyMatch(s -> s.contains(rsGID)));` instead.  As a bonus, this makes your code multi-platform.